# How do I mock global scss variables in my jest test

Tags: vue.js, testing, sass, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am setting up tests for an already existent vue project. The project uses certain scss variables that are injected in the vue config via scss-loader from the env.

`Excerpt of my vue config file`

```js
module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, output),
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `$tabletbreakpoint: ${process.env.TABLET_BREAKPOINT}; $mobilebreakpoint: ${process.env.MOBILE_BREAKPOINT}; $mobpreview: ${process.env.VUE_APP_ADMIN_PREVIEW_MOB};`
      },
      scss: {
        additionalData: `$tabletbreakpoint: ${process.env.TABLET_BREAKPOINT}; $mobilebreakpoint: ${process.env.MOBILE_BREAKPOINT}; $mobpreview: ${process.env.VUE_APP_ADMIN_PREVIEW_MOB};`
      }
    }
  },
  ...
 }
```

However when I try to run my component tests setup using `@vue/test-utils` it fails with the following error

```js
Error: Undefined variable.
   ╷
92 │   @if $mobpreview {
   │       ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  stdin 92:7  root stylesheet

 FAIL  tests/unit/Banner.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run


    [vue-jest] Error: Vue template compilation failed

       8 | export { default as OverflowWatcher } from "./OverflowWatcher.vue";
       9 | export { default as SimpleRadioButton } from "./SimpleRadioButton.vue";
    > 10 | export { default as DropdownSetup } from "./DropdownSetup.vue";
         | ^
      11 | export { default as FitText } from "./FitText.vue";
      12 | export { default as ProgressLevel } from "./ProgressLevel.vue";
      13 | export { default as Banner } from "./Banner.vue";

      at error (node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest/lib/utils.js:122:9)
      at logResultErrors (node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest/lib/utils.js:134:5)
      at processStyle (node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest/lib/process-style.js:104:5)
      at node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest/lib/process.js:87:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at processStyle (node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest/lib/process.js:86:6)
      at Object.module.exports [as process] (node_modules/@vue/vue2-jest/lib/process.js:103:24)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:619:31)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:765:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:822:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/atoms/index.js:10:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.435 s
```

I am looking for a way to make these variables available to all components I am going to be testing.

Comment: Not a good idea to render SASS in this kind of tests, it could be stubbed.

Comment: @EstusFlask question is how to prevent this error from being thrown. Would stubbing solve this?

Given that this is not being imported from any file, how would we stub it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the best way to get these variables is to put them into an scss file and require them globally for the tests using vue-jest's config.

My jest-config file

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  globals: {
    "vue-jest": {
      resources: {
        scss: ["./tests/css-mocks.scss"]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

My mock file
`$mobpreview:false`

Hope this helps someone.